# Change list items in for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I used to work in C++ and I think I am misunderstanding how for-loops (or iterations) work in R. I want to change list items in a for loop, but the for loop seems to make a temporary copy and only change that? How can I prevent this? This seems like a trivial beginners question, but I was unable to find a tutorial / question on stackoverflow about why this happens.

Code:

```
myList <- list(a=1, b=1, c=1, d=1)
for(item in myList){item <- 3}
myList
# Expected output: 3,3,3,3 - Real output: 1,1,1,1
# Additionally, I now have a variable "item" with value 3.
```

Comment: `myList[] <- 3` You are not changing elements of the list by `item <- 3` - you are only putting the value `3` in the object `item` (this you are doing several times).

Comment: You should use something like `for (i in seq_along(myList)) myList[[i]]<-3`. You are right in thinking that `item` is just a copy of an element of `myList` and changing it won't change `myList`.

Comment: @ jogo: My question is - why not? I can do `print(item)` and it outputs the item from the list. What is the general rule here, when is a new object created instead of accessing the existing one?

Comment: @nicola: This might work, I'll try it. Is there a way to still do it like in C++? My variable is actually named something like `models$samples_list$samples$predictions` and I would rather not type that every time... It makes for really long and confusing lines :-\

Comment: @nicola: Your way works. If there isn't an (easy to implement) way of doing it without indices, feel free to post this as an answer so that I can accept it and close the question.

Comment: You should use more idiomatic code and shouldn't try to apply the logic of other languages. R and C++ are very different from basically any point of view. It's very likely that what you need can be accomplished with just a `lapply` or a vectorized operation, but need to be more specific to understand what you need.

Comment: @Thomas No, with `print(item)` you only see that the object `item` has the value `3`. Running through the loop it is initialised by the value of one list element each turn. Then you are overwriting the object with the value `3` (i.e. giving the object `item` a new value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for(item in myList)` creates a new object called `item`

If you want to refer to the items from the list, it would be better to do it by calling either their position with `myList[1]`, or their name with `myList[["a"]]`.

You can for-loop through the list by using the index (as one of the comments suggested).

```
myList <- list(a=1, b=2, c=4, d=5)
for(i in 1:length(myList)){
  myList[i] <- 3
}
myList
```

But I would recomment a vector approach. Check this out:

```
myList <- list(a=1, b=2, c=1, d=5)
myList=='1'
myList[myList=='1']=3
myList
myList[names(myList)=='a']=9
myList
```

Now you do not have any redundant variables.

This is actually the recommended approach in R. For-loops are too computationally expensive.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @nicola, `lapply` should be a good option. Here is an example based on your question.

```
myList <- list(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1) # output: 1,1,1,1
lapply(myList, function(x) 3) # output: 3,3,3,3
# lapply iterates over every list item
```